# Python Expected:in error

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to figure why I am getting a error with this script. line 18 seems to be the issue but being new to python its slow going trying to figure it out....any suggestions?

```
import sys
from Registry import Registry

reg = Registry.Registry(sys.argv[1])
def rec(key, depth=0):
    print "\t" * depth + key.path()

    for subkey in key.subkeys():
        rec(subkey, depth + 1)

rec(reg.root())
try:
    key = reg.open("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Current Version\\Run")
except Registry.RegistryKeyNotFoundException:
    print "Couldn't find Run key. Exiting..."
    sys.exit(-1)

for value in [v for v key.values() \
                   if v.value_type() == Registry.RegSZ or \
                      v.value_type() == Registry.RegExpandSZ]:
    print "%s: %s" % (value.name(), value.value())
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your line 18 comprehension on one line, compressed:

```
[v for v key.values() if ...]
```

This is a syntax error; you are missing an `in`.  The proper form for a comprehension is

```
a for b in iterator [,filter expression]
```

so you need

```
[v for v in key.values() if ...]
```

Comment: So that fixed that issue and then I get another one:           Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wl.py", line 4, in <module>
    reg = Registry.Registry(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @MaasaiMara well, you didn't provide enough arguments when calling your program on the command line.  You should ask a new question (and, preferably, accept an answer) instead of commenting on this one.